# Relationships and ordering in Puppet with roles and profiles

Tags: puppet

I've searched around and even asked some LLMs but I can't make sense of it.

We have an environment that implements the roles and profiles architecture.

```
data/
  global.yaml

environments/
  production/
    data/ 
      nodes/
        database.example.url.yaml
      roles/
        mariadb.yaml
      common.yaml
    manifests/
      site.pp
    hiera.yaml
  development/
  ...

module-site/
  profile/
    manifests/
      mariadb.pp 
      tls.pp
      freeipa.pp
```

The `environments/production/hiera.yaml` and `environments/production/manifests/site.pp` define that the `common.yaml`, nodes and roles and `/data/global.yaml` hierarchy is correctly found by puppet. This all works.

```
---
version: 5

defaults:
  datadir: "data"
  data_hash: "yaml_data"

hierarchy:
  - name: "Environment"
    paths:
      - "common.yaml"
      - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}.yaml"
      - "roles/%{role}.yaml"
  - name: "Global"
    datadir: "../../data"
    paths:
      - "global.yaml"
```

The `environments/production/data/roles/database.example.url.yaml` implements the `mariadb.yaml` role.
The `environments/production/data/roles/mariadb.yaml` implements the profiles `mariadb`, `tls`.
The `environments/production/common.yaml` implements the `freeipa` profile for everything in that environment.

These profiles are generalized implementations. Specificallly the tls and freeipa profiles are separated because they are used used independently from eachother. `freeipa` is always implemented and `tls` only when necessary.

Now the problem I have is that when i apply this role, the `tls` profile is ran before the `freeipa` profile, but there is a dependency between the two. `tls` depends on `freeipa`.

Now I know that within a class or puppet manifest relationships and ordering are as simple as using `before`, `requires` ,`->` or even `stages`. But since these are separate profiles and they are implemented in separate yaml files I can't use any of those techniques.
I tried playing around with the Hiera entries, but hiera only facilitates lookups and not execution hierarchy so this had no effect.

What is best practice on how to do force relationships and ordering in a setup like this? How do I make sure the order of implementation is global > common > node/roles/profiles?

Edit:
To clarify my question further here is the contents of database.example.url.yaml:

```yaml
---
role: mariadb
```

mariadb.yaml then contains:

```yaml
classes:
  - "profile::mariadb"
  - "profile::tls"


## parameters for mariadb
profile::mariadb::username:: foobar
profile::mariadb::password:: development 
... 


## parameters for tls 
profile::tls::certificates: ...
```

the common.yaml contains:

```yaml
## Classes
classes:
  - "profile::freeipa"

#freeipa parameters
profile::freeipa::role: "example"
...
```

Since tls and freeipa are defined in two different files, how do I define relationships and ordering here? tls and freeipa are different implementations.

Comment: I don't quite follow you when you say that your data *implement* your roles or profiles.  Roles and profiles can have associated data, but conventionally, they are all implemented as *classes*.  And if your roles were classes then that would be one place where you could declare ordering relationships between your profiles.

Comment: On the other hand, if one profile has a dependency on another, then it probably should express that itself.

Comment: A role imports classes. 
For instance if a server is an application server, needs a monitoring agent, and tls it imports the classes "profile::application_server", "profile::monitoring", "profile::tls", and then sets some parameters for these. So the role implements (in other words uses, calls, imports)  the profiles to create the role "application-foo". 

Does this clarify my usage of the word "implements" ?

Comment: I know well how Puppet classes and external data work, and I'm intimately familiar with the Roles & Profiles pattern.  What I *don't* know is what this question means when it says that various *Hiera data files* implement roles.  Your comment does not help with that, except to suggest that you might have meant something different from what you wrote.  If indeed you have conventional role classes that declare your profile classes then what I wrote in my initial comment applies: the role classes are a natural place to declare any ordering relationships you need.

Comment: I edited the question to try and clarify our roles and profiles setup, and clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here.

First, your hiera hierarchy list for the environment is upside-down and should go from most-specific to least, as shown in the docs[1].

e.g.

```yaml
---
version: 5

defaults:
  datadir: "data"
  data_hash: "yaml_data"

hierarchy:
  - name: "Environment"
    paths:
      - "nodes/%{::trusted.certname}.yaml"
      - "roles/%{role}.yaml"
      - "common.yaml"
  - name: "Global"
    datadir: "../../data"
    paths:
      - "global.yaml"
```

Secondly, regarding the dependencies, it is possible to set the metaparameters via hiera data, *if you are pulling those in and including them in the parameters which are passed to the class*.

It looks like you are trying to do all this via hiera instead of in the profiles themselves, where it would be best practice to express the dependencies via Puppet DSL.

Options you have are:

1. Add a `require` metaparam to your hiera data, something like this:

```yaml
---
profile::tls::extra_params:
  # Note that this has no quotes due to the way it's interpreted by yaml and Puppet
  require: Class[profile::freeipa]

profile::tls::certificates: ...
```

..then ensure that your profile passes this to the class inclusion:

```
class profile::tls (String $certificates) {
  # ...
  $extra_params = lookup('profile::tls::extra_params', Hash, 'deep')
  tls { 'foo':
    certificates => $certificates,
    *            => $extra_params,
  }
}
```

2. As above but hard-code the `require => Class['profile::freeipa']` entry on the `tls` declaration.  This is considered better practice than adding dependencies via hiera as in (1).

e.g.

```
class profile::tls (String $certificates) {
  # ...
  tls { 'foo':
    certificates => $certificates,
    require      => Class['profile::freeipa'],
  }
}
```

Whichever you do, note that depending on the class needs you to ensure that 'containment' is handled correctly by the classes.[2]

3. There's also a `require` function which simplifies this in the manifests[3]:

```
class profile::tls (String $certificates) {
  require profile::freeipa

  # ...

  tls { 'foo':
    certificates => $certificates,
  }
}
```

..and it looks like this will do the same, possibly without the containment problems.

This is all just jotted down without testing, to give you an idea.  Hopefully it's accurate enough to be useful!  :)

[1] https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/hiera_config_yaml_5.html#config_syntax

[2] https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/lang_containment#lang_containment

[3] https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/6/lang_relationships.html#lang_rel_require